# vector equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Suppose you have an equation of the form $Hx=Ky$, where $x,y$ are vectors of length $n,m$ respectively ($m>n$) and $H,K$ are matrices of orders $n \times n,n \times m$ respectively. Is there some kind of name for it?

Comment: If you write this as $(H|K)(x|-y)^T=0$, isn't this just the kernel of
a family of linear equations?

Comment: Well yes, but I was hoping for something more revealing. :)

Comment: A linear equation.

Comment: A system of linear equations